# jQuery text() call preserves newlines in Firefox but not in IE

Tags: jquery, cross-browser, whitespace

I'm doing:

```
alert($("#div").text());
```

on something like this:

```
<div id="div">
&lt;div&gt;
Some text
&lt;div&gt;
</div>
```

Why the escaped content?  Because it is sometimes malformed and I don't want it interfering with or breaking the rest of the document.

In FF it shows up preserving newlines.  In IE7 it doesn't.  I need to preserve the white space.  This content is actually going in a textarea for editing.

And before anyone recommends a rich text editor, this code isn't really HTML.  It's a custom dialect.

So how do I keep the newlines in IE?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It looks like this is my problem: [The Internet Explorer innerHTML Quirk](http://stud3.tuwien.ac.at/~e0226430/innerHtmlQuirk.html):

> However, innerHTML has a problem in
>   Internet Explorer.
>
> The HTML standard requires a
>   transformation on display of content.
>   **All kinds and amounts of adjacent
>   whitespace are collapsed into a single
>   space.** This is a good thing - just as
>   an example, it allows me to add a lot
>   of line breaks into this source file
>   without having to worry about weird
>   line breaks in the displayed text.
>
> Internet Explorer applies these
>   transformations on assignment to the
>   innerHTML property. This seems like a
>   good idea: it saves a little time
>   during display, because if the
>   in-memory representation is already
>   normalized, then the browser doesn't
>   have to normalize whenever it needs to
>   display the text.
>
> There are exceptions to the
>   normalization rule, though. Notably,
>   these are the <textarea> element, the
>   <pre> element and, in CSS-aware
>   browsers, elements with any value but
>   normal for the white-space property.
>
> Internet Explorer does not respect
>   these special cases. The third makes
>   their optimization a bad idea, because
>   white-space might change at runtime,
>   for example through the DOM. In any
>   case, Internet Explorer will normalize
>   all assignments to the innerHTML
>   property, thus causing the effect
>   demonstrated below.
>
> This text fills the textarea at page
>   load. This, too, contains line breaks
>   and multiple spaces. Formatting is
>   preserved here as well, except that
>   the UA may break lines.

(emphasis added)

And indeed if I change it to:

```
<div id="div">
<pre>
...
</pre>
</div>
```

and

```
$("#div pre").text()
```

or simply:

```
<style type="text/css">
#div { white-space: pre }
</style>
```

it all magically works.

Answer (score 8):

Not sure if this would help, but maybe you could try this:

```
#div {
  white-space: pre;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

See [here](http://www.codingforums.com/archive/index.php/t-155570.html) for a workaround:

> The hack is to first clone the element
>   you want the contents of, using
>   cloneNode().
>
> Next you create a `<pre>` element with
>   createElement(), and then append your
>   cloned node to it.
>
> Now you can get the innerText of that
>   create `<pre>` element, and just delete
>   the temporary objects. You now have
>   whitespace preserved text :)
>
> ```
> var cloned = targetElement.cloneNode(true);
> var pre = document.createElement("pre");
> pre.appendChild(cloned);
> var textContent = pre.textContent ?
>   pre.textContent : pre.innerText;
> delete pre;
> delete cloned;
> ```
>
> The reason I clone the element is
>   because the appendChild() would pull
>   it out of the DOM and it's pain the
>   re-insert back at the correct position
>   in the DOM.
>
> Hopefully this helps a few people out
>   there :)