# Capture text including line breaks, whitespace from DOM in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, dom, markdown

Suppose I have the following HTML on the page:

```
<div id="Test">
One
Two
</div>
```

and this jQuery:

```
var contents=$("div#Test").html()
```

In Chrome and Firefox, the resulting string `contents` includes line breaks - that is, between "One" and "Two" there's character code 10. In IE, though, it seems to collapse any white space and line feeds to a single space (character code 32).

I want to take `contents` and pass it to a Markdown engine, so I need the whitespace and linefeeds to come through as is. How can I do this?

Comment: After some further poking around, found the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/656605/jquery-text-call-preserves-newlines-in-firefox-but-not-in-ie

Comment: Close the question please if you have a solution.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
var contents = $(div#Test).clone();
```

Comment: That returns a jQuery object containing a clone of div#Test - not helpful at all. I need the text contents of div#Test.