# problem with IE which removes new lines from $("#content").text()

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

problem with IE which removes new lines from $("#content").text()

HTML Code

```
<div id="content">
<p>hello world</p>
<p>this is a paragraph</p>
</div>
```

jQuery Code

```
alert($("#content").text());
```

result **(IE)** IE removes new line (\n) how can i fix this problem ?

```
hello worldthis is a paragraph
```

result **(FF)**

```
hello world
this is a paragraph
```

take a look :
http://jsfiddle.net/vB3bx/

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/656605/jquery-text-call-preserves-newlines-in-firefox-but-not-in-ie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure you're going to find a solution using text() if you consider the following:

> Due to variations in the HTML parsers
>   in different browsers, the text
>   returned may vary in newlines and
>   other white space.

at http://api.jquery.com/text/

Answer (score 2):

It works fine if you use the div's innerText property. Try replacing

```
alert($("#content").text());
```

with

```
alert( document.getElementById( "content" ).innerText );
```

Answer (score 2):

Internet Explorer normalizes all white-space and new-line characters into the SPACE character. As far as I know, there is nothing you can do about it.

btw, it seems that IE9 beta changed this behavior. I get new-lines in it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure Sime Vidas is correct. I've tried just about everything and whatever I try (innerText, innerHTML, jQuery methods, TextRange, cloning element and putting it inside a pre element etc etc) white space is removed. I'm guessing IE will just remove it on any type of call. It clearly is there during rendering since a white-space:pre will show it, but retrieving it through javascript will always remove the white space except for pre and textarea content.

This behavior has changed in IE9. The only solution in older versions would be to replace new line characters with 
 tags (or anything really, semicolon etc) on the server if possible and then replace them back into \n in javascript after retrieving the text content.