# Jquery split() returns array with indexes in FF and Chrome but only one index in IE

Tags: jquery, arrays, split

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery text() call preserves newlines in Firefox but not in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/656605/jquery-text-call-preserves-newlines-in-firefox-but-not-in-ie)

I got some issues with this code in IE:

```
var frameFromValues = $('#getData').contents().find("body table tbody tr#c_"+ currencyFrom).text().split('\n');
console.log(frameFromValues);
```

Console in Chrome shows:

```
["", "          KRA", "          Fenix", "          1", "          1", "      "]
```

Console in IE 9 shows:

```
KRAFenix11
```

And because of that, when I try to get a value by its index like this:

```
cFrom = frameFromValues[5];
```

It says "Undefined" in IE, but it works perfectly fine in Chrome.

How do I make it work in IE?

Comment: have a look at it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308134/trim-in-javascript-not-working-in-ie

Comment: I've already added:
String.prototype.trim = function() {return $.trim(this)}

Gonna try the double quote.
Edit: No luck with double quotes. I'll see if freakish link will help me clear it out.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/656605/jquery-text-call-preserves-newlines-in-firefox-but-not-in-ie It's not about `split` ( which works correctly, try it in IE console ), it's about `text()` function. Basically IE skips `\n` and thus `split` returns one element array.

Comment: @freakish I tried to wrap the data within <pre></pre> but that did not solve the problem.

Comment: @estrar Did you also try setting CSS rule `#div { white-space: pre }`? What version of IE we are talking about?

Comment: @freakish Sorry, I forgot to include the pre in the selector. Seems to work now! You could post it as an answer if you want the credit I suppose.

Comment: @estrar Cheers! I'm glad it is working. The solution is not mine, so I won't take any credit for it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `trim();` function

Comment: give proper explanation with example, you can write/modify code as well

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trim use:

```
cFrom = frameFromValues[5].replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
```

Comment: frameFromValues[5] is undefined in IE, so it wouldn't really matter?

Comment: I see, instead of the text(), try innerhtml()