# Displaying a popup without being minimized

Tags: javascript, popupwindow

I have several links in a page that opens a popup window to display the contents of these links.

On Chrome when I click on a link (see code below) the popup window appears front and when I click on a second link, the content changes and the popup its still front: This is the behavior I want to have.

But with Firefox and IE, when I click on the first link the popup appears and when I click on the second link, the content changes but the popup window is minimized.

How to have the same behavior as Chrome on Firefox and IE?

Here's the code:

```
function openpopup(popurl,winName){
   winpops=window.open(popurl,winName,'toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,width=1020px,height=300px,left=125px,top=300px,scrollbars=yes').focus();
} 


<a href="centent1.txt" onclick="openpopup(this.href,'window1'); return false;">centent1</a>
<a href="content2.txt" onclick="openpopup(this.href,'window1'); return false;">centent2</a>
```

I edit the message to not create a second topic.
With IE the text displayed in the popup window does not contain newlines, it is unreadable. Is there something to add more for proper formatting?

Comment: I resolved the first issue by adding the method "focus" (see edited code).

Comment: I resolve the second issue by adding <pre></prev> between my content.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/656605/jquery-text-call-preserves-newlines-in-firefox-but-not-in-ie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add .focus()

```
function openpopup(popurl,winName){

    winpops=window.open(popurl,winName,'toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,width=1020px,height=300px,left=125px,top=300px,scrollbars=yes',true)
    winpops.focus();

}
```

Comment: I posted the solution in the same time as you :), thanks.
Now I try to resolve the other issue that I have.